# How to pass table name using the LAST_INSERT_ID keyword in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

How do you to find last identity insert value in MySQL, with table name as parameter?

When I use the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` keyword, I can't get the table name.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that, indeed.

I suggest you to work it at the application level - in PHP/Python/Ruby/Perl, etc

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality, due to scope issues.
Without calling `LAST_INSERT_ID` in the context of a transaction, there is no way to know if the value is actually related to your insert or someone else's.